# NSAlert - Added Buttons not appearing in the correct Order

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsalert

I'm trying to create an NSAlert with 2 buttons.

```
    let a = NSAlert()
    a.messageText = "Do you want go to A or B?"            
    a.alertStyle = .informational
    a.addButton(withTitle: "Yes")
    a.addButton(withTitle: "No")
    a.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!, completionHandler: { (modalResponse) -> Void in
    if modalResponse == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn { // do stuff}
```

Problem is that the Button `No` Appers before `Yes` and the second button appears to be preselected.Why is this happening?

I need the buttons to appear in the order in which they are added and no button preselected.

Comment: Buttons are placed starting near the right side of the alert and going toward the left side (for languages that read left to right).

Comment: @ColdLogic okay....thanks .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fix order by adding first "No" button then add "Yes"
- Disable preselection by setting keyEquivalent to ""

  ```
  let alert = NSAlert()
  alert.messageText = "Do you want go to A or B?"
  alert.alertStyle = .informational
  alert.addButton(withTitle: "No")
  alert.addButton(withTitle: "Yes")
  alert.buttons[0].keyEquivalent = ""
  ...
  ```

[image]